# Converting string representation of array (of string) to the array in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, unicode

I have an unicode array and I want to convert it to array. 
Given input format and output format below:

```
p = u'(abcd, pqrs, fghj, mjki, loki)'
```

And I want output as below:

```
output = ('abcd', 'pqrs', 'fghj', 'mjki', 'loki')
```

Comment: I think you mean to convert it to a tuple instead, not an array. Also what have you tried here?

Comment: and your array is probably a list

Comment: What encoding is the input?  Looks a bit like yaml but not quite.  Would it be enough to just fish out all uninterrupted character sequences?

Comment: why would `output = [x.strip() for x in p.strip("(").strip(")").split(",")]` not work?

Comment: Is something like `'(abcd, "de,ef", loki)'` possible? And if yes, how should it be handled?

Comment: "I want x." Then write some code to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p = u'(abcd, pqrs, fghj, mjki, loki)'
output = [x.strip() for x in p.strip("(").strip(")").split(",")]
print(output)
```

this will retain unicode though:

```
[u'abcd', u'pqrs', u'fghj', u'mjki', u'loki']
```

Answer (score 0):

Very dirty way, but:

```
>>> tuple(u'(abcd, pqrs, fghj, mjki, loki)'[1:-1].split(', '))
('abcd', 'pqrs', 'fghj', 'mjki', 'loki')


p = tuple(p[1:-1].split(', '))
```

So, I think you could improve your input data before to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can `replace()` the brackets with an empty string beforehand, the split the string by comma `','`, and apply `str.strip` on each element with `map()`:

```
p = u'(abcd, pqrs, fghj, mjki, loki)'

print(tuple(map(str.strip, p.replace('(', '').replace(')','').split(','))))
```

Which outputs:

```
('abcd', 'pqrs', 'fghj', 'mjki', 'loki')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks *nearly* like one of the many available YAML syntaxes, I propose to patch it to be correct YAML and then use a proper YAML parser:

```
import yaml

p = u'(abcd, pqrs, fghj, mjki, loki)'
print(yaml.load('[' + p[1:-1] + ']'))
```

or

```
print(yaml.load(p.replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']')))
```

This way also nested structures (should they appear) would be parsed properly.

For a better performance (if the structures are huge), you might even consider this:  `p.translate({40:91, 41:93})` for translating the parentheses to brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
p = u'(abcd, pqrs, fghj, mjki, loki)'
data = tuple(map(str, re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', p)))
```

Output:

```
('abcd', 'pqrs', 'fghj', 'mjki', 'loki')
```